# Conditional widget visibility in layout XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'd just like to ask if it's possible for widgets to have conditional visibility within the layout XML?

Specifically, I have 2 layouts that each have a ListView.  I've also implemented a custom layout for the list items.

The custom list item layout has 3 buttons, however, for one of the activities, one of the buttons isn't relevant and must be removed/hidden.

Is it possible to accomplish this in the layout XML?  I'd really rather not create another custom list item layout just to remove one button for one activity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think its possible... u hv to do that in java file itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in activity a button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: I was hoping not to do that.  But it looks like there's no other way.

Comment: After searching in vain, looks like performing the change in code is the only way.